# Ext js for responsive UI

Tags: extjs, responsive-design, fluid-layout

Is Ext js a good choice for the responsive UI? I am being told that extjs does not support responsive UI very well. Does that mean I need to go for a framework  something like bootstrap?

Thanks,
guyan

Comment: You can add responsive plugins in Ext Js 5 and look for actual screen size.  There is also sencha touch which you can use for mobile phones.  It's a good framework to use if you are building enterprise solutions. If it's just a one off simple app there are far easier frameworks to use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Until version 4, ExtJs didn't support responsive design. It adapted it's content to the available space, but did not allow for media queries.

As of version 5 (very recent, version 5.0 released in June 2014), ExtJs now natively supports responsive design. Personally, I didn't yet make the step of upgrading to version 5, so I can't share my experience, but it looks promising. Have a look at this [article](http://www.sencha.com/blog/designing-responsive-applications-with-ext-js/). 
The drawback: they say to support only tablets, not phones. If you need to support phones, you have to do your own tests to find out what the limits are.